# Can I add a function to a svg polygon in the css section?

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I am very new to svg's and adding javascript to it.

I am trying to generate graphs which get all their features thru a css section. Now I like to add functions to the different objects but I am not even sure if this is possible like I did in my example because it is not working:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11,dtd">
<svg width="9668pt" height="2132pt" viewBox=0.00 0.00 9668.29 2132.00" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
    <style type="text/css"><![CDATA[
      .node:hover polygon { stroke: yellow; fill: yellow; onclick:'myFunc(evt)';}
      .node: polygon { stroke: yellow; fill: yellow; onclick:'myFunc(evt)';}
    ]]></style>
    <script type="text/javascript"><![CDATA[
      function myFunc(evt) {
        //do sth...
      }
    ]]></script>
  </defs>
  <g id="graph0" class="graph" transform="scale(1 1) rotate(0) translate(4 2128)">
    <title>MyTest</title>
    <polygon fill="white" stroke="none" points="-4,4 -4,-2128 9664.29,-2128 9664.29,4 -4,4"/>
    <g id="myTestNode" class="node">
      <title>Box</title>
      <polygon points="7270.09,2124 7208.09,-2124 7208.09,-2088 7270.09,-2088 7270.09,-2124">
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Does anyone has an idea how to make this working except adding the `onclick=myFunc(evt)` to every polygon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that does not work. CSS is for presentation only. There are many ways to use CSS selectors to attach behaviour. The most low level is querySelector and querySelectorAll. IMHO the easiest and most commonly used is jquery.

as promised here is the snippet...

```js
$("rect").hover(function(event) {
  $("#out1").text("hover: " + event.target.getAttribute("class"))
})
$(".same").click(function(event) {
  $("#out1").text("click: " + event.target.getAttribute("class"))
})
$(".other").click(function(event) {
  $("#out1").text("some other element was clicked")
})
```

```css
.one {
  fill: red
}
.two {
  fill: green
}
.three {
  fill: blue
}
.four {
  fill: yellow
}
rect:hover {
  fill: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="200" height="200">
  <rect class="one same" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="50" />
  <rect class="two same" x="50" y="0" width="50" height="50" />
  <rect class="three other" x="0" y="50" width="50" height="50" />
  <rect class="four none" x="50" y="50" width="50" height="50" />
</svg>

<div id="out1"></div>
```

Comment: Great, thanks for the info. Looking forward to your snippet.